# Option in Atom text editor to open files folded?

Tags: atom-editor

The hotkey `Command + Alt + Option + Shift + [` folds all code. I love this!

But, when I open a file, the code loads unfolded. Is there a preference I can set to make the code load folded, or fold immediately?

Comment: For others coming here, the sequence ```⌘ + option + shift + [```  is the sequence for modern Pulsar/Atom installations.  alt/option are the same key so you only use it once.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct option in Atom but there is package that remembers the folds made for a file - https://atom.io/packages/remember-folds